# Redirect /ask to /questions/ask for convenience

Tags: feature-request, questions, redirection

Chrome autocompleted *stackoverflow.com*, but didn't provide any indication the correct URL was `/questions/ask`, not `/ask`, so I had no idea the former was the correct URL.

Really small thing, but it would be kinda cool/neat if the system autoredirected the URL.